# Controlling security on model updates in RESTful Spring MVC / HATEOS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Consider the following object:

```
class User {
   Long userId
   String emailAddress;
   boolean isLocked;
}
```

If I implement an endpoint for the `User` resource, as follows:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, User updatedUser)
    {
        User dbUser = userRepository.find(userId)
        // map updatedUser to dbUser
        userRepository.save(dbUser);
    }
}
```

Is there currently a standard way to expose the `/user/{userId}` endpoint, but restrict updates of specific fields based on user privileges?

E.g.  I may wish to restrict updates to the `isLocked` property to users with `ROLE_ADMIN`, whilst still allowing the user to update their email address.

Note - this question doesn't pertain strictly to Spring HATEOS - I'm interested in any Spring standard solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities comes to my mind:

- validation (`@Valid`)
- binder configuration (`@InitBinder`)

You can validate the incoming object and check for such changes. Or you can set-up `WebDataBinder#setAllowedFields` within your `@InitBinder` method based on user authorities. The latter one would be probably the easiest way. However instead of returning validation error your application will ignore the fields completely.